# Why the delete button is deleting all af the items instead a single one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, fetch, vuex

After creating a new to do item in the list, after clicking the delete button all of the new tasks are deleted insetead the single one. I'm expecting to be deleted only the propriete one with a passed id with it.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-bootstrap-vue-dynamic-img-bkwixg?file=pages%2Findex.vue,store%2Findex.js,components%2FTask.vue

```js
// Child component

<template>
    <p class="content">
      {{ task.todo }}
    </p>
    <button @click="() => deleteTask(task.userId)" class="delete">
      Delete
    </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['task'],
  methods: {
    deleteTask(id) {
      this.$store.dispatch('deleteTask', id);
    },
  },
};
</script>

// Parent component

<template>
  <Task v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id" :task="task" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    tasks() {
      return this.$store.state.tasks;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getTasks').then((data) => console.log(this.tasks));
  }
};
</script>

// Store

export const state = () => ({
  tasks: [],
});

export const actions = {
  async getTasks(context) {
    const res = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/todos/user/5');
    if (res.ok) {
      let result = await res.json();
      context.commit('setTasks', result.todos);
    }
    return res.ok;
  },
  async deleteTask(context, id) {
    const res = await fetch(`https://dummyjson.com/todos/${id}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'appication/json;charset=utf-8',
      },
    });
    if (res.ok) {
      let result = await res.json();
      context.dispatch('getTasks');
    }
    return res.ok;
  },
};

export const mutations = {
  setTasks(state, data) {
    state.tasks = data;
  },
};
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, but you have misspelled the `Content-Type` value: it should be "application/json"

Comment: Also, you seem to delete all TODO items for the given user rather than a specific TODO item. Try using `task.id` instead of `task.userId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but shouldn't be that you are passing in the `task ID` of the task you want to delete and not the `user ID`?

```js
<button @click="() => deleteTask(task.id)" class="delete">
  Delete
</button>
```

Compare to :

```js
    <button @click="() => deleteTask(task.userId)" class="delete">
      Delete
    </button>
```

Update :

There it work for me :

```js
 async deleteTask(context, id) {
    const res = await fetch(`https://dummyjson.com/todos/${id}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(console.log);
    if (res) {
      let result = await res.json();
      context.dispatch('getTasks');
    }
    return res;
  }
```

```js
completed: true
deletedOn: "2023-05-06T14:01:35.302Z"
id: 103
isDeleted: true
todo: "Go to a local thrift shop"
userId: 5
```

I did as I mention above and added the `task.id` instead of `user.id` and then I removed the `res.ok` just to `res`.

Then added `.then` and removed the headers. I don't think it matters but I looked at the docs and the example didn't use it so.

The only thing left for you is to update the list and maybe add some error handling if something doesn't goes as planned.

Update :

To fix that the list isnt render is because you need ot update the state of tasks in the store. Right now the `deleteTask` action is dispatching the `getTasks` which fetches the tasks from the server and updates the store.

But its asynchronous, so the state may not be updated before the component is rerendered. That's why the list is "right" in the console logs but not as you see it in the actual DOM tree.

```js
async deleteTask(context, id) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://dummyjson.com/todos/${id}`, {
    method: 'DELETE',
  });
  if (res.ok) {
    // filter the tasks in the state to remove the deleted task
    const tasks = context.state.tasks.filter(task => task.id !== id);
    context.commit('setTasks', tasks);
  }
  return res.ok;
}
```

Now this will update the state of the tasks in the store immediately and the component will rerender with the updated list.

I went with the `res.ok` and tried to keep it as your code looked from the start.

Comment: Probably, but in that case, if I chenge it to id - I'm getting the 404 error and no items are deleted

Comment: How do the API endpoint look then? And if you console the 404 error what's is saying?

Comment: The API looks like 'https://dummyjson.com/todos/1'  and the 1 - is the id

Comment: And the error liiks like https://dummyjson.com/todos/undefined 404
_calle

Comment: I manage to get a deleted task. I updated my answer above.

Comment: I wonder why now the item is deleted but the list isn't rerendered in the DOM

Comment: Now it works fine, but only at the console, so that it Is showing that the item was deleted. But somehow the id of the newtask is not corresponding to the id of the same deleted task, nor does the useId, I wonder why now. So the list isn't rerendered with the deleted items

Comment: Have a look at the updated answer and maybe that will help you with the problem

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the `DELETE` functionality!!
When I looked the code and the API responses, the issue is not with the delete functionality.
The issue is with the `todos/add` API through which you create a new task.
I could see the response with json including the `completed: false`, indicating that the task has not been created.

**Then why is it showing as a new task when created and why all new tasks are vanishing on deleting a particular task ?**

1. While creating a new task, you are appending the task to your tasks list when the API response is `OK`. (of course, the API is responding with OK status though the task is not being stored )
2. Once after deleting of a particular task, You are re-fetching the task list from the server ( and it'll give only those tasks which are being stored. And as I mentioned earlier, no task is being saved so it appears that `it deleted all the tasks instead of one`

**What to do now ?**
You better go, look at the backend where you wrote the code to store the tasks and check why it's not being stored.

NOTE : Once after creating the tasks, you are looking at the status to be `OK`, you better also look for the response with containing `completed : true`